# Android change TextView's color

Tags: android

i have a textView and i want to give it the color `0X33CCFF`
i tried this

```
firstHint.setTextColor(0X33CCFF);
```

but the textView seems to just disappear , what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your just missing one bit, try the following:

```
firstHint.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#33CCFF"));
```

Comment: when i put your code , the program got exception and can't run , when i removed it , the programs works

Comment: @user1476842 I take it from your second comment you fixed the exception?

Answer (score 1):

can try with small 'x'

firstHint.setTextColor(0x33CCFF);

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you forgot to give Alpha value!.

Change

```
firstHint.setTextColor(0X33CCFF);
```

To

`firstHint.setTextColor(0xFF33CCFF);`  // Here First FF denotes the alpha value

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html), the TextView.setTextColor() takes either an int, or a ColorStateList. 0x33ccff is an int. However, as Vipus Shah says, you have no alpha value (which says how transparent the color is). The format for a hex color is as following: 
0xAARRGGBB, where AA is, of course, alpha.

There is no difference between lower case and upper case letters, so 0XfFaEEb is the same as 0xffaeeb or 0XFFAEEB.

This is your code:

```
firstHint.setTextColor(0xFF33CCFF);
```

Alpha is FF(255), which means it's entierly visible.